# Using template cass from DL/so/dyib

Tags: c++11, templates, dllexport

ALL,

I have following code inside my library:

```
//header
template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass : public MyBaseClass {
public:
    MyClass(T obj);
    ~MyClass();
};

//cpp file
template<class T>
__declspec(dllexport) MyClass<T>::MyClass(T obj) : MyBaseClass() {
    // body of the constructor
}

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::~MyClass() { }
```

Now I'm trying to use this class.

Turns out I can't write:

```
// header
class Foo
{
private:
    MyClass<T> *obj;
};

// cpp file

void Foo::some_func()
{
    obj = new MyClass<Test>();
}
```

as I get the compilation error, but I also can't write:

```
// cpp file
void Foo::some_func()
{
    Test *test = new Test();
    MyClass *obj = new MyClass<Test>( test );
}
```

as I get a linker error.

So what is the proper way to use template class from the library?

TIA!!

Comment: You can't export a template from a DLL. A template does not by itself produce any machine code - it's a recipe to stamp out an infinite family of classes *at compile time*. Whereas a DLL contains machine code, to be used at run time. Related: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I have 2 structs that differ by extra member(s). I need to pass them in the MyClass constructor. How do you solve it without duplicating the code?

Comment: You could use templates - you just can't put them into a DLL. If for some reason you have to use a DLL, then you'd need to find a way without templates.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, ok, got it. Out of curiosity - how STL solves this? In the meantime I can probably try to override the constructor and (unfortunately) duplicate some code. Is there a better solution?

Comment: The C++ standard library implementation is almost entirely in the headers. As to whether there's a better solution - it's hard to say, as you haven't described the problem in need of solving.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, `I have 2 structs that differ by extra member(s). I need to pass them in the MyClass constructor. How do you solve it without duplicating the code?` - this is the quote from my first reply. Doesn't it describe the problem?

Comment: What will that constructor do with those structs? What code is common, and what is different between the two? Show some code that demonstrates the problem - the definition of the two structs, the code in `MyClass` that you want to avoid duplicating, the proposed usage by the clients of `MyClass`.